# OpenAPI spec is valid in earlier versions (openapi-generator 3.x) but fails validation in newer versions

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I am trying to generate a server stub for a service whose API is described as an OpenAPI file (https://developer.loadsmart.com/api/openapi.yaml)  I am attempting to use openapi-generator (https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to accomplish this.

When checking out previous revision of the repository (3.3.4) I can validate the api file as such:

```
$ java -jar openapi-generator-cli-3_3_4.jar validate -i api.yaml
Validating spec (api.yaml)
No validation issues detected.
```

When using 4.3.1 version of repository (latest 4.x branch version I believe), the API file no longer validates:

```
$ java -jar openapi-generator-cli-4_3_1.jar validate -i api.yaml
Validating spec (api.yaml)
[main] ERROR i.s.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter - failed to read resource listing
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'openapi': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2868)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1914)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:773)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4231)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2711)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readResourceListing(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:210)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.read(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:123)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readWithInfo(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:94)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.readWithInfo(SwaggerParser.java:42)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.readLocation(SwaggerConverter.java:89)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.Validate.execute(Validate.java:52)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.OpenApiGeneratorCommand.run(OpenApiGeneratorCommand.java:32)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator.main(OpenAPIGenerator.java:61)
[main] ERROR i.s.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter - failed to read resource listing
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'openapi': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 8]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1840)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:722)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2868)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1914)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:773)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readTreeAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4231)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2711)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readResourceListing(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:210)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.read(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:123)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter.readWithInfo(SwaggerCompatConverter.java:94)
    at io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser.readWithInfo(SwaggerParser.java:42)
    at io.swagger.v3.parser.converter.SwaggerConverter.readLocation(SwaggerConverter.java:89)
    at io.swagger.parser.OpenAPIParser.readLocation(OpenAPIParser.java:16)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.Validate.execute(Validate.java:52)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.OpenApiGeneratorCommand.run(OpenApiGeneratorCommand.java:32)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator.main(OpenAPIGenerator.java:61)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:119)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.Validate.execute(Validate.java:54)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.cmd.OpenApiGeneratorCommand.run(OpenApiGeneratorCommand.java:32)
    at org.openapitools.codegen.OpenAPIGenerator.main(OpenAPIGenerator.java:61)
```

And finally, when using 5.0 version (5.0.0 or 5.0.1), the API file seems to have additional validation issues:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-5_0_0.jar validate -i api.yaml
Validating spec (api.yaml)
Errors:
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/load-offers/offers/{offer_id}/related'(get).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items
      is missing
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/matches/{match_id}/reject'(post).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items
      is missing
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/matches/{match_id}/accept'(post).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items
      is missing
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/load-offers/loads/'(get).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items
      is missing
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/matches/'(get).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items is
      missing
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/load-offers/loads/{load_id}'(get).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items
      is missing
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/load-offers/loads/{load_id}/related-offers'(get).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items
      is missing
    - attribute paths.'/api/v2/carrier/{driver_id}'. Declared path parameter driver_id needs to
      be defined as a path parameter in path or operation level
    - attribute paths.'/api/v2/shippers/accounts/{account_id}'. Declared path parameter
      account_id needs to be defined as a path parameter in path or operation level
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/shipments/{shipment_id}/appointment_suggestions?start_date={start_date}'.
      Declared path parameter shipment_id needs to be defined as a path parameter in path or
      operation level
    - attribute paths.'/api/v2/load-offers/offers/{offer_id}'. Declared path parameter offer_id
      needs to be defined as a path parameter in path or operation level
    - attribute paths.'/api/v2/intermodal/quotes/{batch_id}'. Declared path parameter batch_id
      needs to be defined as a path parameter in path or operation level
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/load-offers/offers/{offer_id}'(get).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items
      is missing
    - attribute paths.'/api/v2/capacity/{capacity_ref_number}'. Declared path parameter
      capacity_ref_number needs to be defined as a path parameter in path or operation level
    - attribute
      paths.'/api/v2/load-offers/offers'(get).responses.200.content.'application/json'.schema.items
      is missing
    - attribute paths.'/api/v2/shipments/{shipment_id}'. Declared path parameter shipment_id
      needs to be defined as a path parameter in path or operation level
Warnings:
    - Unused model: PhoneNumber
    - Unused model: EquipmentType
    - Unused model: TotalWidth
    - Unused model: TotalLength
    - Unused model: TotalHeight
    - Unused model: Requirements
    - Unused model: ShipmentMode

[error] Spec has 16 errors.
```

I'm trying to understand why stricter validation seems to have been introduced in newer versions of the openapi-generator, without any obvious option to update the older file.  The OpenAPI specification version for the api.yaml file I'm using is 3.0.1.  I have tried looking on the OpenAPI and Swagger sites to get any clues for breaking changes between different versions of openapi-generator but I'm not coming up with anything very helpful.

Comment: It seems to be linked to this commit https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/commit/22c6c0ca68aee25ca7923f7eff85079f9dc08376#diff-39df2f8f9c950efe2c5d7696edf2ccd88562149f487873b3bc64a0d10fb6d79d could you try running with `openapi.generator.rule.recommendations=false` ?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It seems that commit only dealt with recommendations, so disabling them didn't seem to have any effect in my case, because the generator is returning errors.

Comment: Your OpenAPI file is NOT valid, and the errors reported by openapi-generator 5.x are actual errors. If you import your OAS file into https://editor.swagger.io, you'll see even more errors. Maybe openapi-generator 4.x did not actually support OAS3 validation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce it.

[This commit](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/commit/f6f5c9b8b905023329cf70d867b22e46719a0c5d) is the one that introduced the change, it is linked to [this issue](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/5471):
[image]

The problem was that `validate` did not really behave in the same way `generate` was behaving and thus they introduced the same kind of validation.

For more details, the `validate` command now makes the following call

```
SwaggerParseResult result = new OpenAPIParser().readLocation(spec, null, options);
```